# How to change loading logo in Flet?

Tags: python-3.x, flet

I am new to the Flet framework. I have noticed that while running some small apps, I see the Flet logo in the middle of the screen being animated while stuff is being loaded in the background. I want to know whether the logo can be changed and whether I can add some custom animations of my own?

Answer (score 2):

1. first create a folder in the folder that your main.py is located at and name it "assets"

[See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iRXf.png)

2. now inside the assets folder create another file called "icons" and put your logo picture in it but note that the name of the logo picture must be "loading-animation.png"
3. now simply copy and paste this code in your main.py:

```
import flet
from flet import Page, Text


def main(page: Page):
    page.add(Text("Hello, world!"))


flet.app(target=main, assets_dir="assets", view=flet.WEB_BROWSER)
```

Hope this would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

the Flet logo can appear at 2 occasions and both can be modified to your liking.

1. **Splash at app entry:** If you would like your app to load with a different splash image, check out this example app, that uses a custom image as a splash: https://github.com/flet-dev/examples/tree/main/python/apps/custom-loading-image.
2. **Loading indicator when something is run:** This can be changed and controlled through the `page.splash` property, check out the snippet below that changes the flet loading thingy to a ProgressRing:

```py
from time import sleep
import flet as ft

def main(page: ft.Page):
    def button_click(e):
        page.splash = ft.ProgressBar()
        btn.disabled = True
        page.update()
        sleep(3)
        page.splash = None
        btn.disabled = False
        page.update()

    btn = ft.ElevatedButton("Do some lengthy task!", on_click=button_click)
    page.add(btn)

ft.app(target=main)
```